Retrieve the maximum market cap of a token from transactions
I need to retrieve the maximum market cap (in USD) of a token, starting from its transactions. particularly I'm looking at the swaps, which have this structure:
type: 'SWAP';
  info: {
    swapper: string;
    tokens_swapped: {
      in: {
        token_address: string;
        amount: number;
      };
      out: {
        token_address: string;
        amount: number;
      };
    }
 }
}

for each transaction I calculate the token price:
const tokPrice = solAmount / tokAmount;
at the end I get the higher price along with it's Timestamp, and I calculate the output as follow:
const solanaCap = (tokenSupply / maxPrice) * USD_SOL_VAL

Token supply does take into account the minting.
I'm doing something wrong, cause the output value does not resemble the actual token MC, any hints?
Thanks
